# how do I exit the purple command screen?

Tags: command-line

I switch my laptop on then it's intro is normal then suddenly it appears for me somestuff written and at the end written failed
Then after 1 minute/lesser a list of commands or operating text appears for me then they want me to type some commands
I tried holding shift or lshift and no grub menu appeared 
Please help me

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So you have line saying like `grub>`  and then you can type stuff ? or something else , like `initramfs $` ? Can you post picture to imgur and link here  ?

Comment: initramfs this is what appearing for me

Comment: http://imgur.com/7OAR5Fs here's the link

Comment: OK . . . There's a related question - [Error when installing: “unable to find a medium containing a live file system”](http://askubuntu.com/q/15425/295286). There are several answers, try to see which one works,  and if any of them don't work let us know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installing: “unable to find a medium containing a live file system”](http://askubuntu.com/q/15425/58950) and/or [How to fix “(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system” on custom Live USB?](http://askubuntu.com/q/511893/58950)

Comment: Change the usb from a 2.0 port to the 3.0 port. If that doesn't work, check the MD5: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM